# WPF Dialog not modal?

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I have a Window which I show by dispatching the ShowDialog() call on the ui thread (I am on another thread):

```
myMainWindowDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool?>(myDialog.ShowDialog));
```

myDialog's Owner has been set to myMainWindow. When the dialog shows it is correctly always on top however I am able to interact with the Window behind! (defeating the purpose of making it modal which is required). I used to do the same thing, i.e. dispatch the call from another thread and it used to work, i.e. was modal. Now for the life of me I cannot figure out why it is not. I cannot paste my whole project code here - can you think of anything that would make the Window non modal??

Comment: How about `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: Nope, I cannot hold up the other thread - it was BeginInvoke when it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting: I digged out a backup and found the cause:

Another dialog, Window shown using ShowDialog, Dialog A, is opened before this one, then this dialog, Dialog B, is shown ontop of it. When Dialog B has loaded I now hide Dialog A, Window.Hide(), then show it again when Dialog B closes. **This hiding of Dialog A somehow makes other windows behind Dialog B interactive to the user again, while Dialog B is open!**

I am guessing the reason is because showing multiple dialogs at once is not ordinary and when I hide one of them WPF thinks it can enable the other Windows again.. But that is just my guess!

A solution is to instead of hiding make very small your other Dialog (NOTE: setting Visibility to Hidden has the same result as calling Hide()):

```
    public void HideDialog()
    {
        myDialogA.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
        myDialogA.Height = 0;
        myDialogA.Width = 0;
    }

    public void UnHideDialog()
    {
        myDialogA.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    }
```

(The business requirement for showing multiple dialogs is beyond the scope of this question , before I get called evil kanevil for using modal windows, and not relevant, if you are wondering how one can show multiple dialogs see here: [Is it safe to show multiple dialogs in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269809/is-it-safe-to-show-multiple-dialogs-in-wpf))

Comment: if Dialog A is the Owner of Dialog B you should get the behavior you want ... ? if you do so, you dont need to hide Dialog A cause you can not access it without close Dialog B.

Comment: I already have the behaviour I want: i.e. which ever dialog was shown last the user can interact with - they can actually interact with any dialog if they can see it but they cannot see A typicallly - I just hide it in case B does not completey cover A.

Comment: The behaviour I didnt want was for the user to interact with the window behind the dialogs - which has happening if I hide one of them using Hide().